# Error on load Chrome Custom Tab in Android 11

Tags: android-studio, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

`Chrome custom tab` work in every other device. Only `error` in `Android 11`.

Here is my code how I put I code in my app.

```
ImageView adCustomBannerImage= findViewById(R.id.adCustomBannerImage);
    adCustomBannerImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String urlCustomBannerAd= getResources().getString(R.string.urlCustomBannerAdQureka);
            CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

            CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent=builder.build();
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(urlCustomBannerAd));
        }
    });
```

When I click on `ImageView` then this error come in `Android 11`

```
2022-03-11 10:22:21.344 3059-3059/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme, PID: 3059
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1018)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:425)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api16Impl.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:830)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:279)
    at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl(CustomTabsIntent.java:376)
    at com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

After too much research on this topic I found 3 helpful page. But I am not much pro developer, So I cann't understand these documentations terms.

1. [Using Custom Tabs with Android 11](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/custom-tabs-android-11)
2. [Package visibility in Android 11](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9)
3. [Fulfilling common use cases while having limited package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#java)

So any developer can tell me pls, what is need to change in my code.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **getApplicationContext()** and pass **your_activityname.this**

```
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(your_activityname.this,Uri.parse(urlCustomBannerAd));
```